# Swing Flickering

Tags: java, swing, flicker

I've a problem with Swing , i'm trying to do a calendar and the date is displayed thanks to a `JLabel` that i've put in a `JPanel` and when I call the function `setText` to change the date displayed the image flickers for a few milliseconds all the components are not in the good place and then everything displays well.

Even when I launch my application the images flickers and i noticed that every component's `paintComponent` function is called three times ...

To summarize I did a `Jpanel` called `Container` which contains all the `JLabel` and `Jtextfield`, I did override their `paintComponent` to call `setBounds`.
And then i add the container inside the frame and I display it.

Class draw :

```java
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class draw {
    JTextField B3;
    JTextField C3;
    JTextField D3;
    JTextField E3;
    JTextField F3;
    JTextField B4;
    JTextField C4;
    JTextField D4;
    JTextField E4;
    JTextField F4;
    JTextField B5;
    JTextField C5;
    JTextField D5;
    JTextField E5;
    JTextField F5;
    JTextField B6;
    JTextField C6;
    JTextField D6;
    JTextField E6;
    JTextField F6;
    JTextField B7;
    JTextField C7;
    JTextField D7;
    JTextField E7;
    JTextField F7;
    JTextField B8;
    JTextField C8;
    JTextField D8;
    JTextField E8;
    JTextField F8;

    public draw(){}
    public void drawCalendar() {
        B3 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 170, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }

        };
        C3 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 170, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D3 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                System.out.println("IL MA REPAIT !");
                this.setBounds(870, 170, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E3 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 170, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F3 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 170, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        B4 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 200, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        C4 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 200, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D4 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(870, 200, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E4 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 200, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F4 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 200, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };

        B5 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 230, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        C5 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 230, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D5 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(870, 230, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E5 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 230, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F5 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 230, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        B6 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 260, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        C6 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 260, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D6 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(870, 260, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E6 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 260, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F6 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 260, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        B7 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 350, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        C7 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 350, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D7 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(870, 350, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E7 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 350, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F7 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 350, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        B8 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(470, 380, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        C8 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(670, 380, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        D8 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(870, 380, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        E8 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1070, 380, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        F8 = new JTextField(15) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(1270, 380, 200, 30);

                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
```

Example class

```java
public class example {
    int weeknumber = 0;
    String month = "June";
    JLabel A1;
    public void updateLabelText(){
        weeknumber++;
        A1.setText("<html>week" + weeknumber + "<br>" + "<center>" + month + "</html>");

    }

    public example(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Planning");
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) dimension.getWidth() - 50, (int) dimension.getHeight() - 50));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Integer weeknumber = 23;

        draw draw = new draw();
        draw.drawCalendar();

         A1 = new JLabel("<html>week " + weeknumber + "<br>" + "<center>" + month + "</html>") {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds(70, 40, 400, 100);
                this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);




                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                g.fillRect(0, 25, 400, 60);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(0, 25, 400, 60);
                super.paintComponent(g);


            }
        };
        JPanel Container = new JPanel();
        Container.setBounds(0, 0, (int) dimension.getWidth(), (int) dimension.getWidth());
        Container.add(A1);

        JButton next_week = new JButton("Suivante") {


            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                this.setBounds((int) dimension.getWidth() / 2 + 70, 10, 150, 50);

                super.paintComponent(g);

            }
        };
        next_week.addActionListener(e -> {
            updateLabelText();

        });
        Container.add(next_week);
        Container.add(draw.B6);
        Container.add(draw.C6);
        Container.add(draw.D6);
        Container.add(draw.E6);
        Container.add(draw.F6);
        Container.add(draw.C7);
        Container.add(draw.D7);
        Container.add(draw.E7);
        Container.add(draw.F7);
        Container.add(draw.B8);
        Container.add(draw.C8);
        Container.add(draw.D8);
        Container.add(draw.E8);
        Container.add(draw.F8);
        frame.add(Container);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example example = new example();

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] so people have a chance to see what might be causing your problem.

Comment: I edited my question with an example that reproduce the same problem thanks

Comment: Like that, but minimal.

Comment: 1. Don't set properties of the component in the painting method. (setalignment(), setBounds()). 2 There is no need for custom painting. If you want a background color then a) make the component opaque by using `setOpaque(true)` and b) if want space around the compnents then use `setBorder(...)` to set an `EmptyBorder`. Also, in general you should NOT be using setBounds(). Swing is designed to be used with layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution of my problem. I'm going to explain how I solved it if someone encounters the same problem than me it might help.

First of all if you want to use setBounds make sure that you have set the frame's layout as null and in my case I created a JPanel where I add all my components so I set its layout to null.

```java
JPanel Container = new JPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name of your APP");
Container.setLayout(null);
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Then write a class that extends the component that you wanna use so in my case I wrote the following classes

```java
class label extends JLabel{
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
        public label(String text,int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.setText(text);
            this.setBounds(x, y, width,height);
            this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        }
}


class button extends JButton{
        public button(String text,int x, int y,int width,int height){
            this.setText(text);
            this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        }


} 
class textField extends JTextField{

        public textField(int col,int x,int y ,int width,int height){
            this.setBounds(x, y, width,height);
            this.setColumns(col);

        }

}
```

This way works well if you want to control everything in your frame and set absolute position.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I think it might be helpful in some cases if you don't want to support every screen size/resolution for example .. But if you want to support a lot of differents screen size, resolution etc it's definitely not the way to go.